# how to merge two array into one in python and numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I want to merge two arrays `(a,b)` ( each `shape = (30,192,192,1)`) into one (input) like this `shape = (30,192,192,2)`.
Is there anyone who can help me?

My code is as below:

```
input = np.ndarray((a.shape[0], a.shape[1], a.shape[2],2))
input[:,:,:,0] = a
input[:,:,:,1] = b
```

but I get this error:

```
input[:,:,:,0] = a
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (30,192,192,1) into shape (30,192,192)
```

Comment: Try `input[:,:,:,[0]] = a`, or `input[:,:,:,0]=a[:,:,:,0]`.  i.e match shapes.  `numpy` broadcasting can add dimensions at the beginning, not the end.

Comment: Thank you very much! it works well!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can reshape the a and b arrays before:

```
a=a.reshape((30,192,192))
input[:,:,:,0] = a
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments!